# Create model diagram from existing Access database

Tags: database, ms-access, diagrams

Is there any software that can make model diagram for existing Access database (.accdb), similar as WorkBench do for MySQL database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

within the MS Access, you can goto [Database tools] tab and select [Relationships] there you will see or be able to drag all your tables and create your relationships.

Comment: Yes, but there is no column type descriptions